# My Profile Link in My Site SharePoint 2010 is redirecting to an incorrect URL

Tags: url, my-profile

I am having issues in my site for SharePoint 2010.

The 'My Profile' link in the user navigation menu is redirecting to an incorrect profile page URL. The correct URL should include the account name for that specific user so that the profile page will be viewed properly, but What happens is the URL becomes 'http://mysite/directory/person.aspx' where it should be 'http://mysite/directory/person.aspx?accountname=user1'

I have checked my my site host location, and it is pointing the mysitehost site collection and when I view the profile page manually, the data is correct and the links in the search results are also correct.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, if you will go to your profile in SharePoint it will point you to person.aspx page, it can automatically display your profile not others. If you click to any others user names you will be redirected to link like people.aspx?accountname=domain\login. This page will show you profile of other user, but in general it is the same page, just you needn't go to your profile by link with accountname specified.
May be I misunderstood your question, but behavioral like this seems to be correct.